# debug Auth Login returning true but login failed

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a simple log in application. Whenever I log in it prints the error message: Invalid Username or password.
I tried debug($this->Auth->login()) but it always returns true and despite this log in gets failed. 
Another problem is if I put $this->request->data inside login(),it logs in even with wrong password.
Following is the code.
AppController.php

```js
  
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller
{
 public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array('loginAction'=>array('controller'=>'students','action'=>'login'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'students','action' => 'add'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'students','action' => 'login'),
   'authError'=> 'You must be logged in to view this page!',
   'loginError'=> 'Galat Username or Password !',
        'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('userModel' => 'Student','fields' => array('username' => 'email','password'=>'password')),
'authorize'=>'Controller'      
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->userModel='Student';
        $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
    }



}
```

StudentsController.php is:

```js
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class StudentsController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Session', 'Number', 'Text', 'Time');

public $components = array('Paginator', 'Auth', 'Flash', 'Security', 'Session');
 
 public function beforeFilter()
 {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->Auth->allow('login','add','index');
 }
 
 public function login()
 {
  //if already logged-in, redirect
  /*if($this->Session->check('Auth.Student'))
  {
   $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
  }*/
  //if we get the post information,try to authenticate
  if($this->request->is('post'))
  {
   if(debug($this->Auth->login()))
   {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '.$this->Auth->user('name')));
    /*$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());*/
    
   }
   else
   {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password from student controller!'));
   }
  }
 }
```

Login view is:

```js
<div class="users form" >
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Student'); ?>
    <fieldset >
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your email and password.'); ?>
        </legend>
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
<?php
echo $this->Html->link("Register",array('action'=>'add'));
echo"\r\n";
echo $this->Html->link("Forgot Password",array('action'=>'add'));

?>
```

Student.php

```js
   <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Student Model
 *
 */
class Student extends AppModel {

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
 public $primaryKey = 'enroll_no';

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
 public $validate = array(
  'enroll_no' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    'message' => 'Please enter your enrollment number',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ), 
  'name' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    'message' => 'Please enter your full name.',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'course' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    'message' => 'Please enter your course e.g. B.Tech MCA',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'majors' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'year_of_admission' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    'message' => 'Your custom message here',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'email' => array(
   'email' => array(
    'rule' => array('email'),
    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'password' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'phone_no' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'guardian_name' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false,  //Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  ),
  'guardian_phone_no' => array(
   'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
    'allowEmpty' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'last' => false,  //Stop validation after this rule
    'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
   ),
  )
 );



 public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        
    /* password hashing */    
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried debug($this->Auth->login()) but it always returns true and
>   despite this log in gets failed. Another problem is if I put
>   $this->request->data inside login(),it logs in even with wrong
>   password. Following is the code. AppController.php

Guys, start using [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) and [API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-AuthComponent.html#591-616)... On that page is a big red box telling you that...

> **In 2.x $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in
>   with whatever data is posted**, whereas in 1.3
>   $this->Auth->login($this->data) would try to identify the user first
>   and only log in when successful.

Comment: having done $this->data, login is successful but on wrong password too. How to resolve that.